# My kendo template Field does not bind the data in Grid Column

Tags: kendo-grid

I use a Kendo Grid to bind my data .

I check some null condition while data binding but it does not bind the data it shows an error in template binding.

```
 { field: 'Phone', title: 'Phone', template: '<span>#if(Phone != null){#<span># Phone#</span> #}# </span>' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just try like this ......u miss template binding in kendo grid(format is like (#=Fieldname#)

{ field: 'Phone', title: 'Phone', template: '#if(Phone != null){##= Phone# #}# ' }

now you try this...its working